# Why does a variable in PowerShell expand to `-encodedCommand` instead of its actual value?

Tags: powershell

I want the `$mydate` variable or the command `Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd` to expand in the following command line (note the [curly braces required by the `svn.exe` client](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates):

```
$mydate = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd

svn log https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ -r {Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd}

svn log https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ -r {$mydate}
```

In both cases I am getting the following error:

```
svn: E205000: Syntax error in revision argument '-encodedCommand'
```

Why does the variable becomes `-encodedCommand`? Should I escape curly braces? How? Tick '`' does not work:

```
Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format..
At line:1 char:1
+ svn log https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ -r `{$mydate`}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment, but try:

`svn log https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ -r "{$($mydate)}"`

The outer " quotes convert it all into a string, so ignores the curly braces. The $() allows the variable to be correctly interpreted (not as a string).

Comment: Nice, though the `$(...)` isn't strictly necessary here (`"{$mydate}"` will do), given that the only thing to interpolate is a simple variable reference, not an expression; for the full rules, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375

Answer (score 2):

To complement [yaquaholic's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52722018/45375) with background information:

***Unquoted* use of `{...}` has special meaning in PowerShell**: it creates a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks) (type `[scriptblock]`), which is a reusable piece of PowerShell code that can be passed as an argument or stored in a variable for later execution on demand.

Therefore, **to pass arguments with embedded `{` or `}` characters, *quote* them** (with `'...'` (literal string, e.g., `'{foo}'`) or `"..."` (expandable string, e.g. `"{$foo}"`), as needed).

---

The behavior that PowerShell exhibits as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 7.0 with *unquoted* `{...}` is a [known problem](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5187):

A script block has no meaning *outside* of PowerShell, such as when passing arguments to an external program like `svn`.

By contrast, calling *PowerShell's own CLI*  - `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell), `pwsh` (PowerShell Core) - with a script block *is* supported, via behind-the-scenes Base64-encoding of the script block's content, with the encoded string passed via `-encodedCommand`, and CLIXML serialization applied to arguments and pipeline input - see [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3319#issuecomment-286291861)

This mechanism is currently - pointlessly - applied to other external programs too, which is why you saw an `-encodedCommand` argument appear.